# Firebase query n items and listen to new only

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query last 5 items and then listen only to new childs. However,
when I add new child, childeventlistener returns the last child from thos 5 i queried earlier.

```
query = myRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(5);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
          // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0
          int oldSize = mData.size();
          List<ChatMessageEntity> data = new ArrayList<>();
          for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // do something with the individual "issues"
            ChatMessageEntity chat = issue.getValue(ChatMessageEntity.class);
            data.add(0,chat);
          }
          mData.addAll(data);
          adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(oldSize, mData.size());
        }

        query.addChildEventListener(newMessageListener);
      }

      @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });
```

Comment: It will return the same last 5 items, because you have ordered it by key, may I ask why do you need the last five ?

Comment: @ChesterCobus 5 is a random number), plan is simple - load last n items, load new items if they are published and load old one when use scroll to the end of loaded content

Comment: The solution for the new posts is to get first 5 posts (could be new or old posts), and then when user scrolls load the next 5 and so on.

Comment: Just additional tips, you should try using `SortedList` object instead of `List`. It saves me huge amount of time because it automatically filter same object, update the value if two object have same keys, basically everything I want from a sorted `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type of scenario you're better off using a `ChildEventListener`. This has a method `onChildAdded` that will be called for (up to) five children initially and then for each new child added later.

```
query = myRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(5);
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        ChatMessageEntity chat = issue.getValue(ChatMessageEntity.class);
        data.add(0,chat);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(mData.size()-1);
    }

    ...

    @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore these
    }
});
```

The above code works, but is missing handling of `previousChildName` (as children that arrive later might not be added to the end of the list), `onChildChanged`, `onChildMoved` and `onChildRemoved`. Adding handling for all of these is a fun exercise, but quite a bit of work and a bit tricky to get right. If you want to complete the work, I recommend taking a look at the [`RecyclerViewAdapter` in FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter.java) and its work horse [`FirebaseArray`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java) - which are nicely battle tested.

For more information see the [Firebase documentation on listening for child event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events).

Comment: defenetly clean approach, but its timeconsuming. I tried to load 40 initial items and it took considerable longer to fully load

Comment: On the wire there is no difference between a `ChildEventListener` and a `ValueEventListener` on the same location/query. So the time to load is exactly the same. But there is likely a difference in how efficient the painting in Android is. That's why why expose extra an "all data loaded" event in FirebaseUI: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/458

Answer (score 0):

The best i make up is to load required number of items, save key of the newst one. Remove item with that key from list.  Create new query which starts from key of the newest and add childEventListener to it.

```
query = myRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(20);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
          // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0
          int oldSize = mData.size();
          //List<ChatMessageEntity> data = new ArrayList<>();

          for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // do something with the individual "issues"
            ChatMessageEntity chat = issue.getValue(ChatMessageEntity.class);
            chat.key = issue.getKey();
            mData.add(chat);
            //data.add(0, chat);

          }
          //mData.addAll(data);
        }
        Log.e("mcheck", "onDataChange:  " + mData.get(0).message);
        Query query;
        if (mData.size() > 0) {
          query = myRef.orderByKey().startAt(mData.get(mData.size() - 1).key);
          olderstKey = mData.get(0).key;
          mData.remove(mData.size() - 1);
          adapter.notifyItemRemoved(mData.size()-1);
          adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, mData.size());
          //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          query.addChildEventListener(newMessageListener);
        } else {
          myRef.addChildEventListener(newMessageListener);
        }

      }

      @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });
```